# mod_rewrite: url rewriting plus subdomain (wildcard) rewrite at the same time

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain, wildcard

I have two rules in my `.htaccess` file for url rewriting:

1. for subdomain rewriting: `xxx.domain.com` is internally redirected to `file.php?item=xxx`

   ```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^\.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]

   RewriteRule ^$ /file.php?item=%2 [QSA,nc]
   ```
2. ordinary rewriting:

   ```
   RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_)(:!-',]+)/?$ file.php?item=$1 [L]
   ```

What i need to achieve is writing a third rule that will combine these two rules without being in conflict with them. Namely, below (or above) this lines i need to have something like that:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^\.]+)\.domain\.com/([A-Za-z0-9_)(:!-',]+)$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^$ /anotherfile.php?item1=%2&item2=$1 [QSA,nc]
```

so that http://xxx.domain.com/yyy will be redirected to anotherfile.php?item1=xxx&item2=yyy

any ideas that will work, or what is the correct way of it?

Comment: For future reference, this type of question is more geared towards ServerFault (http://serverfault.com/).  Run by the StackOverflow team, it's exclusively for server and system administrators.

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_)(:!-',]+)/?$ /file.php?item1=%2&item2=$1 [QSA]
```

It uses conditions of the first rule and URL path pattern of the second.